# How to define Specific Bucket Only Allow S3 Full Access Policy to that bucket only?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have created below S3 policy for a user-name - john under account : 416XXXXXX, so that he is only allowed to use consolek S3 folder.

But this is giving following error : 
**This policy contains the following error: Has prohibited field Principal For more information about the IAM policy grammar, see AWS IAM Policies.**

What exactly I am missing here ?

```
{  
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "Stmt1487252735934",
      "Action": "s3:*",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::john",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": [
          "arn:aws:iam::416XXXXXX:user/karthik"
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Related: [Grammar of the IAM JSON Policy Language](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_grammar.html).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AWS Trust Policy Has prohibited field Principal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45478585/aws-trust-policy-has-prohibited-field-principal)

Answer (score 1):

Is this an S3 bucket policy or an IAM policy? Your question says it is a bucket policy, but the error says it is an IAM policy. An IAM policy does not contain a Principle section, since it is assigned directly to the Principle that would be using it.

Comment: So why `Principal` block appears in [Grammar of the IAM JSON Policy Language](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_grammar.html)?

Answer (score 1):

IAM policy does not have Principle section. You can create resource-based policy at http://awspolicygen.s3.amazonaws.com/policygen.html.

Comment: It's `Principal`, not `Principle`, and it has as per [Grammar of the IAM JSON Policy Language](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_grammar.html).