# Creating Policy for SAML's IAM role

Tags: amazon-web-services, saml, saml-2.0, amazon-iam

I'm trying to create a policy for an IAM role for my federated users (authenticating through my SAML provider). I'm following [Creating a Role for SAML 2.0 Federation (Console) - AWS Identity and Access Management](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_create_for-idp_saml.html):

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRoleWithSAML",
      "Principal": {"Federated": "arn:aws:iam::ACCOUNT-ID-WITHOUT-HYPHENS:saml-provider/PROVIDER-NAME"},
      "Condition": {"StringEquals": {"SAML:aud": "https://signin.aws.amazon.com/saml"}}
    }
  }
```

But I get following error:

```
This policy contains the following error: Has prohibited field Principal For more information about the IAM policy grammar, see AWS IAM Policies
```

I tried to Google it but no success. The answer on [AWS Trust Policy Has prohibited field Principal - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45478585/aws-trust-policy-has-prohibited-field-principal) wasn't helpful either. Can someone tell me how can I create policy and role for my SAML provider?

Comment: Can you describe exactly where you are putting this policy, or the exact steps you took? It appears that there are two policies required — a trust policy and a permissions policy.

Comment: Did you change “ACCOUNT-ID-WITHOUT-HYPHENS” to your account number, and “PROVIDER-NAME” to your SAML provider?

Comment: Problem solved. explained it in another post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved. The documentation is old and misleading. If you create a role for SAML provider via IAM Console, automatically it has trust relationship built in there. So, just permissions need to be added.

Answer (score -1):

There is an error in the policy.
You are missing **[]** in the statement.

The correct Policy will be:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Federated": "<COPY & PASTE SAML ARN VALUE HERE>"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRoleWithSAML",
      "Condition": {
        "StringEquals": {
          "SAML:aud": "https://signin.aws.amazon.com/saml"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Try this one