# Getting error: "Has prohibited field Principal", when creating policy

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-policy

I want to create a policy to allow everyone to read my S3 bucket, this is the policy that I have created (I am following [this guide](https://learnetto.com/blog/cloudfront-s3)):

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my-s3-bucket/*",
            "Principal": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

I cannot create this policy, this is the error that I am getting:

> This policy contains the following error: Has prohibited field
>   Principal For more information about the IAM policy grammar, see AWS
>   IAM Policies

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was, I was creating the new Policy in IAM. I had to add the policy in S3, as a bucket Policy:

Select S3 Bucket -> Permissions -> Bucket Policy: paste the policy here

[image]

Note: If you want to grant read permission to anonymous user at the bucket level, then you need to turn off the following two settings.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I have generated the policy which you want using the [Policy Generator](https://awspolicygen.s3.amazonaws.com/policygen.html).

```
{
  "Id": "Policy1567210887639",
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "Stmt1567210883302",
      "Action": [
        "s3:GetObject"
      ],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my-s3-bucket/*",
      "Principal": "*"
    }
  ]
}
```

Check if this works for you.

Comment: Thanks, I tried it and am getting the same error. I pasted the exact script from AWS Policy Generator and still getting this error!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45478585/aws-trust-policy-has-prohibited-field-principal trying checking out the trust policy